# wordpress ajax call keep on running after calling once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I made a wordpress ajax call code in which when i click on a button the the function runs properly and returns the value first time as it should but after that the ajax call to admin-ajax.php keepon running as i can see from developer tools . My code is

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_arete_bp_endorse', 'arete_bp_endorse_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_arete_bp_endorse', 'arete_bp_endorse_ajax' );

function arete_bp_endorse_ajax(){
    global $wpdb;

 $result['type'] = "works";

echo $result; 
wp_die();   
}


function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "my_voter_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/example/js/example.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_voter_script' );

}
```

the example.js file code

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".endorse-bt", function (event){
event.preventDefault();
var type= jQuery(this).attr("data");
var option= jQuery(this).parents("li").attr("data-endorsed-item-name");
var profile_id=jQuery(this).parents("li").attr("data-prf-id");
var login_id=jQuery(this).parents("li").attr("data-lg-id");
 jQuery.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data:{action: "arete_bp_endorse", type : type, option: option, profile_id: profile_id, login_id: login_id},
    success: function( response ){
      //Do something with the result from server
      alert(response.type);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: did [timeout](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) works for you, I am not sure ..

Comment: You mean it send the ajax request again and again OR just the request keeps on pending?

Comment: It completes the request it should do and then keeps on sending request again n again